# Помогите с сайтом. Как разъединить ссылки в html

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылки, которые слева должны быть разъединены

```css
header .logo {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

header .logo span {
 font-size: 2.3em;
 line-height: 45px;
 margin-left: 43%;
 
}

header .about a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
 left: 100px;
 word-spacing: 6px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;

}

#number {
 position: absolute;
 right: 60px;
 top: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
   <span>MoreTours</span>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
  <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#main')">Возможности</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#overview')">Преимущества</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#contacts')">Контакты</a>
  <p id="number">0-000-000-00-00</p>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, не пытаться каждой ссылке присвоить `position: absolute;`.

```css
header .logo {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 35%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

header .logo span {
 font-size: 2.3em;
 line-height: 45px;
 margin-left: 43%;
 
}

header .about a {
 position: relative;
 word-spacing: 6px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;

}

.links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 25px;
  left: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}


#number {
 position: absolute;
 right: 60px;
 top: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 10px;
}

header {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
   <span>MoreTours</span>
  </div>
  <div class="about">
  <div class="links">
      <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#main')">Возможности</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#overview')">Преимущества</a>
      <a href="#" onclick="SlowScroll('#contacts')">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  <p id="number">0-000-000-00-00</p>
  </div>
 </header>
```

А вообще, рекомендую задуматься над тем, что Вы делаете. Строить верстку сайта на абсолютных позициях - плохая практика.

Comment: Спасибо) А тогда на каких позициях лучше делать?

Comment: @danilious `position: relative` (по умолчанию, относительно блока). Для того, чтобы элементы встали в ряд - `display: flex;` или `display: inline-block;` (первый вариант предпочтительнее).